# Transactions and triggers

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I think If a trigger run On Insert, and the insert statement was in transaction, an error in the trigger will return to the transaction and I can catch it and ROLLBACK.

Is that correct? Is there problems or concerns about that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is true unless you actually call `RAISEERROR` yourself in the trigger.  In that case you must actually call `ROLLBACK TRANSACTION` as well.

Answer (score 0):

That is a perfectly valid use of triggers, nothing wrong with it.

Trigger based constraints rely on this method.